# Simple ansible example that connects to new server as root with password

Tags: ansible, provisioning

I want to provision a new vps. The way this is typically done: 1) try login manually as a non-root user, and 2) if that fails then perform the provisioning.

But I can't connect. *I can't even login as root.* (I can ssh from the shell, so the password is correct.)

hosts:

```
 [server]
 42.42.42.42
```

playbook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    ROOT_PASSWORD: foo
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: set root password
      set_fact: ansible_password={{ ROOT_PASSWORD }}
    - name: try login with password
      local_action: "command ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=3 root@{{ inventory_hostname }} 'echo ok'"
      ignore_errors: true
      changed_when: false
    # more stuff here...
```

I tried the following, but all don't connect:

1. I stored the password in a variable like above
2. I prompted for the password using `ansible-playbook -k playbook.yml`
3. I moved the password to the inventory file

   [server]
    42.42.42.42 ansible_user=root ansible_password=foo
4. I added the ssh flag `-o PreferredAuthentications=password` to force password auth

But none of the above connects. I always get the error

> root@42.42.42.42: Permission denied (publickey,password).

If I remove `-o BatchMode=yes` then it prompts me for a password, and does connect. But that prevents automation, the idea is to do this without user intervention.

What am I doing wrong?

This is a new vps, nothing is set up yet - so I'm looking for the **simplest possible example of a playbook that connects using root and a password.**

Comment: Before someone posts about the root password in cleartext, note I said I need a simple example just to get this working. If I can't get this to work as ROOT, then nothing else would work either. Also, as soon as I can get this to work, I'll add tasks to disable root login and password login anyways - this is just bootstrapping for a new vps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  The variable is `ansible_ssh_password`, not `ansible_ssh_pass`. The variables with `_ssh` in the name are legacy names, so you can juse use `ansible_user` and `ansible_password` instead.

If I have an inventory like this:

```
[server]
example ansible_host=192.168.122.148 ansible_user=root ansible_password=secret
```

Then I can run this command successfully:

```
$ ansible all -i hosts -m ping
example | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

---

If the above ad-hoc command works correctly, then a playbook should work correctly as well. E.g., still assuming the above inventory, I can use the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ping:
```

And I can call it like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts
PLAY [all] ***************************************************************************

TASK [ping] **************************************************************************
ok: [example]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************
example                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

...and it all works just fine.

Comment: Thanks larsks! The ad hoc command works for me too. But it's the playbook that doesn't work. The playbook I posted above fails with "Permission denied (publickey,password)". Even when I add the ssh flag `-o PreferredAuthentications=password`

Comment: I've updated the answer showing that a playbook with the same configuration *also* works.

Comment: Thanks for the update, your approach works for me too! BUT, what concerns me though is that you're using "ping" and I'm using "local_action" and sshing manually. Your way works but assumes the vps has python installed... The one I'm testing on does, but the one in production may not (I have a feeling we'll be using something slim which doesn't have anything out of the box, until I provision it... catch-22! ) Which I think is why so many examples use the approach I used above.

Comment: if the remote system doesn't have Python installed, then you use the `raw` module to install it first, e.g., http://blog.oddbit.com/post/2015-10-15-bootstrapping-ansible-on-fedora-23/.

Answer (score 0):

Try using --ask-become-pass

```
ansible-playbook -k playbook.yml --ask-become-pass
```

That way it's not hardcoded.

Also, inside the playbook you can invoke:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: no
```

Comment: I don't think that applies. Unless I'm mistaken (I'm still new to ansible), that only applies once you connect and try to elevate permission. The problem here is not being able to connect in the first place.

Comment: Enable root login over SSH:
As root, edit the sshd_config file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Add a line in the Authentication section of the file that says PermitRootLogin yes. This line may already exist and be commented out with a "#". In this case, remove the "#".
# Authentication:
#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

Comment: That isn't the problem - I can ssh as root normally, it's just I can't do it via ansible. I don't think it's possible as is, but with a small addition, I managed to get it working... see my answer below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

All SO answers and blog articles I've seen so far recommend doing it the way I've shown.

But after spending much time on this, I don't believe it could work that way, so I don't understand why it is always recommended. I noticed that ansible has changed its API many times, and maybe that approach is simply outdated!

So I came up with an alternative, using `sshpass`:

hosts:

```
 [server]
 42.42.42.42
```

playbook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    ROOT_PASSWORD: foo
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

    - name: try login with password (using out-of-band ssh connection)
      local_action: command sshpass -p {{ ROOT_PASSWORD }} ssh -q -o ConnectTimeout=3 root@{{ inventory_hostname }} 'echo ok'
      ignore_errors: true
      register: exists_user

    - name: ping if above succeeded (using in-band ssh connection)
      remote_user: root
      block:
      - name: set root ssh password
        set_fact:
          ansible_password: "{{ ROOT_PASSWORD }}"
      - name: ping
        ping:
          data: pong
      when: exists_user is success
```

This is just a tiny proof of concept.

The actual use case is to try connect with a non-root user, and if that fails, to provision the server. The above is the starting point for such a playbook.

Unlike @larsks' excellent alternative, this does not assume python is installed on the remote, and performs the ssh connection test out of band, assisted by `sshpass`.

Comment: larsks's excellent alternative includes the canonical answer for how to handle things if Python isn't  installed on the remote host (use the `raw` module). This is almost in all cases going to be better than trying to run `ssh` commands yourself.

Comment: @larsks Hey again, I just realised from your profile that you're a redhat dev, so for all I know you're an ansible dev! I meant no disrespect, I'm sure your recommendation is good, but my way makes more sense to me - "KISS". I don't see the downside, it's much simpler, and in line with all the dozens of posts on this topic (just updated, so it actually works!). I'm marking your answer as correct, but for future readers, I recommend mine as a solid alternative, which I'm using personally. Thanks again!

Comment: I do work for Red Hat, but not on Ansible :). I just use it a lot.